# Date.monday() not working for Date.js

Tags: javascript, date

I am trying to use [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) for some date functions. But I am not getting some functions like `Date.march()` and `Date.monday()`. I have downloaded the files from [Datejs](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/downloads/detail?name=date.js&can=2&q=). I am able to see in firebug that the page is getting the content of `date.js`. This is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
   <title>Date</title>
       <script src="date.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


   </head>
   <body>

       <script type="text/javascript">
           alert(2222);
           alert(Date.monday());
       </script>
   </body>


</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Apart from your problem, have a look at http://momentjs.com/ instead, it seems Datejs has not been updated in a long time.

Comment: I will definitely take a moment to check out `momentjs` :)...but I really liked `datejs` because of its ruby like syntax, chaining of methods as I am primarily from Ruby on Rails background..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works for me, have a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AVMDf/1/):

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datejs/1.0/date.min.js"></script>
<script>
  alert(Date.monday())
</script>
```

Comment: thanks a lot...looks like the link from where I downloaded the file has some issues, I used the script in your answer and it is working.

Answer (score 0):

```
Date.parse('2013-08-26').monday() 
# September 2nd

Date.parse('2013-08-26').previous().monday()
# August 19th

Date.parse('2013-08-26').next().monday()
# Sepetember 2nd
```

Datejs does not give the result you may expect when you ask for the "Monday" if the date you give is a "Monday"